# Get original sentences from CoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm going through my data and want to split it into sentences. I'm using pycorenlp.

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
    'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit',
    'outputFormat': 'json'
})
for tempsentence in output['sentences']:
     # store important sentences ...
```

Now I store some sentences which are important for my application.
Some of those contain " or ' and it seems that CoreNLP changes those sentences. " are converted into -LRB- and -RRB- if I remember that correctly.

Is it possible that I can get the orignial sentence from CoreNLP (since I need to do another CoreNLP run later on and if " is now gone, my data doesn't look orgininal and the 2nd CoreNLP run doesn't seem to recognise some quotiations anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download and install the stanza library: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza
2. The returned result will have the original tokens.

example:

```
from stanza.nlp.corenlp import CoreNLPClient
client = CoreNLPClient(server='http://localhost:9000', default_annotators=['ssplit', 'tokenize'])
result = client.annotate("...")
for sentence in result.sentences:
  for token in sentence.tokens:
    print token.word + "\t" + token.originalText
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much - and awesome work, by the way!